# Textbox shrinks(invisible) when layout is match constraint(0 dp)

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWExM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dijqM.png)

One with text invisible is mine and one with text showing in centre is tutors.

I don't understand, I followed all the steps but my text shrinks when I do match constraints (0dp) both layout height and width.

I tried rechecking and repeating what's said in video but I did all same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.